# Linear Regression: Extremely Imbalanced Categorical Features

Tags: r, machine-learning, categorical-data, feature-engineering

I am working on a Kaggle Housing Dataset (https://www.kaggle.com/c/house-prices-advanced-regression-techniques) to predict a house price using several regression techniques. For this project I am using R/Rstudio. However, I ran into a issue when dealing with categorical data. The problem is that most of the categorical features are extremely imbalanced. Here are some of the examples.

```
table(data$Condition2)

Artery  Feedr   Norm   PosA   PosN   RRAe   RRAn   RRNn 
     5     13   2889      4      4      1      1      2 

table(data$HouseStyle)

1.5Fin 1.5Unf 1Story 2.5Fin 2.5Unf 2Story SFoyer   SLvl 
   314     19   1471      8     24    872     83    128
```

The issue that this creates is that when I train-test-split, one of the data can include classes of a categorical feature that is not included in the other dataset. For example, train data can include "RPAn" and "RPAe" from the Condition2 feature, but test set do not include them.

This result in another issue where I train a model and test, it will return an error where the model could not find the classes that it was trained on for the test set. The error looks like this.

```
lm_model <- lm(SalePrice ~ ., pre_train)
summary(lm_model)
lm_result <- predict(lm_model, newdata=validation) 

Error in model.frame.default(Terms, newdata, 
     na.action = na.action, xlev = object$xlevels) : 
  factor RoofMatl has new levels Membran, Roll
```

What would be the right approach to tackle this problem? Are the only way to just delete the  categorical features that are extremely imbalanced(which ends up being majority of the categorical feature in the dataset)? If someone can answer this, that would be super helpful!

Comment: You should use your entire dataset for encoding, and then do your splits.  https://stackoverflow.com/a/55525814/2886575

Comment: @Him, that's the opposite of what your linked answer says!

Comment: "Whatever transformations you do to the train set should be done to the test set before you make predictions" They mean to include things such as one-hot encoding.  If you are mapping the vectors [groucho, 2], [harpo, 3] and [chico, 4] to [1,0,0,2], [0,1,0,3] and [0,0,1,4] respectively, then this is NOT a "learning" activity, it's just a "defining" activity, and you should do this to ALL of your data in the same way, both for your training, your "test" and any future predictions.

Comment: @Him I agree about it not being "learning" and therefore mostly OK, and this is discussed at greater length elsewhere (mostly the root questions are: what does your model try to do when training with constant-0 columns for test-only categories, and what happens to training-only categories?).  But your approach is the second block of code in the answer you linked, headed as "Incorrect", so your link doesn't support your suggestion.

Comment: @BenReiniger this is fair that my link does not support my assertion, but I would like to still stand by my assertion.  The reasoning that the answer I posted gives for not doing the encoding on the cat'd train/test set is that the test set contains things that weren't in training.  This assumes that prediction on the test set is the ultimate goal of the model.  This is naive, I think, unless you're doing toy activities such as Kaggle competitions - the ULTIMATE test will be real-world data, and that data may very well contain unforeseen values that you will need to deal with.

Comment: Attempting to, a priori, consider all possibilities for inputs is the correct thing to do.  Possibly this involves lumping things together as @Dimitri suggests.

This would also fit into a production workflow, which probably looks like "pick a model family, do test/train split, train on train, test on test, report these results and make decisions about model based on these results, then train the production model on ALL available data and put into production."

The test/train thing is for meta-modeling to inform you about the model family, it's not for predictive purposes.

Answer (score 1):

If your intent is prediction and not inference, there are a few ways around this I suppose.

One approach is to NOT make predictions for observations which have new levels.  This is the approach common modelling libraries (like  tidymodels) will take.  It isn't a great approach in my opinion, but it is certainly one approach.

The other is to use domain knowledge to collapse some of the less prevalent groups into larger categories. Maybe it would make sense to group 2 Bed + Den units together with the 2 Bed units.  Maybe it wouldn't.  It's up to you.

Another solution would be to use a random effect rather than a fixed effect.  When new categories appear, random effects can naturally handle them, as I demonstrate below

```r
library(tidymodels)
#> Registered S3 method overwritten by 'tune':
#>   method                   from   
#>   required_pkgs.model_spec parsnip
library(tidyverse)
library(lme4)
#> Loading required package: Matrix
#> 
#> Attaching package: 'Matrix'
#> The following objects are masked from 'package:tidyr':
#> 
#>     expand, pack, unpack

# Generate imbalanced data
set.seed(0)
N = 100
groups = sample(letters[1:3], size=N, replace = T, prob = c(0.95, 0.04, 0.01))
y = model.matrix(~groups-1) %*% c(2, 1, -1) + rnorm(N, 0, 0.24)
d = tibble(groups, y)

# Split up the data
splits = initial_split(d)
train_set = training(splits)
val_set = testing(splits)

#missing b!
train_set %>% 
  count(groups)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   groups     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 a         73
#> 3 c          1

# has b!
val_set %>% 
  count(groups)
#> # A tibble: 2 × 2
#>   groups     n
#>   <chr>  <int>
#> 1 a         25
#> 2 b          1

model = lmer(y~1 + (1|groups), data = train_set)

preds = predict(model, newdata=val_set, allow.new.levels = T)
```

<sup>Created on 2021-10-12 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>

Finally, if there are just one or two categories which don't appear frequently, you could just ignore them.  This approach becomes problematic however when you have many categories appearing a few times and a handful making up the majority of the observations.

All in all, my recommendation would be to use domain knowledge to lump categories together if possible.  If once you've done that and you can't lump categories together in a reasonable way, my recommendation would be to use a mixed effect model.